# Installing Matplotlib on Windows 64-bit and Python 3.5

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip

Since there is not yet a [official release](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/matplotlib) for matplotlib for Python 3.5, I tried to use pip.

```
pip install matplotlib
```

It says I am missing some required dependencies and extensions.

```
REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
                 numpy: yes [version 1.10.0.post2]
                   six: yes [using six version 1.9.0]
              dateutil: yes [using dateutil version 2.4.2]
                  pytz: yes [using pytz version 2015.6]
               tornado: yes [using tornado version 4.2.1]
             pyparsing: yes [using pyparsing version 2.0.3]
                 pycxx: yes [Official versions of PyCXX are not compatible
                        with matplotlib on Python 3.x, since they lack
                        support for the buffer object.  Using local copy]
                libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
                        be found. Using local copy.]
              freetype: no  [The C/C++ header for freetype (ft2build.h)
                        could not be found.  You may need to install the
                        development package.]
                   png: no  [The C/C++ header for png (png.h) could not be
                        found.  You may need to install the development
                        package.]
                 qhull: yes [pkg-config information for 'qhull' could not be
                        found. Using local copy.]
[...]
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-bjiqixce\matplotlib
```

But I have freetype and png installed on my system.

```
C:\Users\me>where ft2build.h
C:\Users\me\libs\GnuWin32\include\ft2build.h
C:\Users\me>where png.h
C:\Users\me\libs\GnuWin32\include\png.h
```

All of these are installed with normal users privileges. What am I doing wrong here?

Edit: yay Python 3.5 version now exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nozdrum,

When installing Matplotlib for python 3.5, I came across the same problem as you. What worked for me was first downloading one of the binary distros for [CMake](https://cmake.org/download/) and then installing VB2010 with the [ISO](http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/E/5/1E5F1C0A-0D5B-426A-A603-1798B951DDAE/VS2010Express1.iso) for VS2010. After I finished the download and install for both CMake and VB2010, I then again ran

```
pip install matplotlib
```

Also, if the previous solution did not work, though the following did not work for me, there is a set of scripts compiled by jbmohler to build matplotlib on windows:

> this is a set of scripts to build matplotlib from source on the MS
>   Windows platform. It builds matplotlib requiring only Visual Studio
>   and CMake as pre-requisites; other library dependencies are embedded
>   in this repository. Any complicated or other dependencies are
>   considered bugs in this build script.
>
> The Python shipped from `http://www.python.org` is compiled with Visual
>   Studio 2008 for versions before 3.3 and Visual Studio 2010 for 3.3 and
>   later. Python extensions are recommended to be compiled with the same
>   compiler. These scripts and the matplotlib setup.py look for the
>   correct version via distutils. The .NET Framework 4.0 is required for
>   MSBuild, but you likely already have it.
>
> In addition to Visual Studio CMake is required for building libpng.
>   For building documentation, you will need to install numpydoc and
>   miktex. The required freetype, zlib, libpng, tcl, & tk source code is
>   bundled with this repository since there is no canonical Windows
>   package manager.
>
> To build & install matplotlib in your Python, do:
>
> ```
> git clone https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib 
> git clone https://github.com/jbmohler/matplotlib-winbuild            
> python matplotlib-winbuild\buildall.py
> ```
>
> The build script will auto-detect Python version & 32/64 bit
>   automatically.
>
> The origin of these scripts is the comment by cgohlke in
>     `https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/1717`

Comment: Thank you so much :D Installing cmake was enough to make the pip installer work.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.